# Incorrect error while testing Django signup page

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am working on a Django app. I want to create a signup page for a new user. After Django gets the form that is submitted and stores the cleaned data, I want it to check and see if the username that was entered already exists. if it exists, I want Sjango to redisplay the page with an error message. It works fine if the username doesn't already exist.

When the username does exist however, I get the following error:

```
ValueError at /signup/
The view users.views.user_signup didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/signup/
Django Version: 2.0.5
Exception Type: ValueError
Exception Value:    
The view users.views.user_signup didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
Exception Location: /Users/omarjandali/anaconda3/envs/MySplit/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py in _get_response, line 139
Python Executable:  /Users/omarjandali/anaconda3/envs/MySplit/bin/python
Python Version: 3.6.2
Python Path:    
['/Users/omarjandali/Desktop/demo/mysplit',
 '/Users/omarjandali/anaconda3/envs/MySplit/lib/python36.zip',
 '/Users/omarjandali/anaconda3/envs/MySplit/lib/python3.6',
 '/Users/omarjandali/anaconda3/envs/MySplit/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload',
 '/Users/omarjandali/anaconda3/envs/MySplit/lib/python3.6/site-packages']
```

The strange thing that I am seeing right now is that I have a print statement that will display the results of the query I wrote to check the username and if it exists in the database. When the form is submitted, it throws the error and in the trace in my terminal it is not printing the statement.

I am entering an existing username. It should make a query and print the results.

Here is my code:

```
def user_signup(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = SignupForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            email = cd['email']
            username = cd['username']
            password = cd['password']
            user_taken = User.objects.filter(username = username).first()
         ** print(user_taken)
            if user_taken == None:
                print('username is good')
                secure_password = make_password(password)
                user = User.objects.create(
                    username = username,
                    email = email,
                    password = secure_password
                )
                login(request, user)
                return redirect('user_profile')
            else:
                print('username is taken')
                form = SignupForm()
                error = "Username is already taken"
                parameters = {
                  'form':form,
                  'error':error
                }
                return render(request, 'users/signup.html', parameters)
    else:
        form = SignupForm
        parameters = {
            'form':form
        }
        return render(request, 'users/signup.html', parameters)
```

I put a ** where the print statement should print:

This is what I am getting in my terminal:

```
[23/May/2018 08:39:27] "POST /signup/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[23/May/2018 08:39:27] "GET /profile/ HTTP/1.1" 200 960
[23/May/2018 08:39:31] "GET /logout HTTP/1.1" 301 0
[23/May/2018 08:39:32] "GET /logout/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[23/May/2018 08:39:32] "GET /login/ HTTP/1.1" 200 516
[23/May/2018 08:39:32] "GET /logout HTTP/1.1" 301 0
[23/May/2018 08:39:32] "GET /logout/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[23/May/2018 08:39:32] "GET /login/?next=/logout/ HTTP/1.1" 200 516
[23/May/2018 08:39:34] "GET /signup/ HTTP/1.1" 200 609
Internal Server Error: /signup/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/omarjandali/anaconda3/envs/MySplit/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 35, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/omarjandali/anaconda3/envs/MySplit/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 139, in _get_response
    "returned None instead." % (callback.__module__, view_name)
ValueError: The view users.views.user_signup didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
[23/May/2018 08:39:47] "POST /signup/ HTTP/1.1" 500 54487
```

It is not even printing the expected results of the query. Can anyone help me with this.

Comment: try to use `try` and `except`. For instance use `try: user_taken = User.objects.filter(username = username).first() expect : User.DoesNotExist: return username raise forms.ValidationError('Username "%s" exists' % username)`

Comment: will this help me figure out why the second it hits that query it stops working and throws the error without printing the results. When it returns a None it prints it out. but when it is not a None, it doesnt even attempt to process.... wouldnt it atleast print that statement. is there an issue with the query... @PanosAngelopoulos

Comment: Not the problem you ask about, but really validating uniqueness should be done in the form itself (via the `clean()` method) rather than in the view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not return response if your form is not valid.

```
def user_signup(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = SignupForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            # YOU code here

        parameters = {
          'form': form,
           # if you need only errors messages
           # 'error': " ".join([x for x in form.errors.values()])
          'error': form.errors.as_ul()
        }
        return render(request, 'users/signup.html', parameters)
```

Comment: so it is showing that the username does exists. But it is not printing. I have it set as error in the parameters. in the html document, I have {{error}} above the form. nothing is showing up tho

Comment: try to modify your template to render form errors [rendering-fields-manually](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually)

Comment: glad to help you

Comment: Another question... The error is displaying as `<ul class="errorlist"><li>username<ul class="errorlist"><li>A user with that username already exists.</li></ul></li></ul>` is there a way to just get it to display the message as a p... the part that says `A user with that username already exists.`

Comment: but if you will have more than one field error you will not know the field name

Comment: I just dont like how it is displaying... it looks off. lets say I dont mine if the field doesnt show up and still want it to show the message without the entire part. how would i be able to do that...

Answer (score 2):

You are not returning a response for `POST` requests when the form is not valid.

The usual fix is to de-indent the final two lines so that you always return a response at the end of the view.

```
def user_signup(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = SignupForm(request.POST)
        ...
    else:
        form = SignupForm()   # Note you should instantiate the form instead of using the form class SignupForm 
    parameters = {
        'form':form,
    }
    return render(request, 'users/signup.html', parameters)
```

To debug why the form is not valid, you can check `form.errors` in the view or template.

As Daniel suggests in the comments, the validation should be done in the form instead of the view. You can then display the form errors in the template, and don't need to add `error` to the context in the view. If your form is a model form, it might be checking uniqueness for you already, in which case all you need to do is display the form errors in the template. See the docs on [working with form templates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/#working-with-form-templates) for more info.